# Handle duplicate keys in python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Sorry in advance if this question has been answered before but I can't seem to find it.

I have panda dataframe like so:

```
id | value1 | value2 | ... | valueN
1  | 321    | 44     | ... | 7766
2  | 5678   | 7638   | ... | 987423
2  | 0971   | 7638   | ... | 1
and so on...
```

I load it correctly and what I want to achieve is an `OrderedDict` which will collapse the double values if needed. For the above example,

the output dictionary should be:

```
{1: ['321', '44', ..., '7766'], 2:['5678,0971', '7638', ..., '987423,1']}
```

Notice that the values of the dictionary are `list` and the values of the list are `strings`.

My code so far is:

```
od = collections.OrderedDict()
for k in df.id:
        if k in od:
            # This key, pre-exists in this dictionary, so we have to append values
            # what should I do here?
        else:
            # new value inserted. proceed.
            od[k] = unordered_dict.get(k)
```

any ideas?

Comment: Load the collection with the key, append the values. Just like you said. Keep writing,  you are on the right track.

Comment: If the key already exists in the dictionary, you should append the list to the existing one using `.extend()`:  `od[k].extend(unordered_dict.get(k))`

Comment: @dejavusansmono i got stuck in this part for over an hour, that's why I posted it here :P

Comment: @Mixalis A whole hour huh. :P

Comment: @DejaVuSansMono I'm not an expert in sarcasm like Sheldon Cooper, but I think that was one...

Comment: @Mixalis Sorry, ozgur's comment should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you need, at least it worked on my dummy data:

```
all_data = {}                   
for column in df.columns.values[1:]:
    data = df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: ','.join(x[column])).to_dict()
    for key in data:
        if key in all_data.keys():
            all_data[key].append(data[key])
        else:
            all_data[key] = [data[key]]
```